# how to get data from stored data base in php using search box

Tags: php, database

I am using search form to search values from data base but i am failed to get results my table name is"user" in data base please help

**data.html**
 my code look like

```
<form action="data2.php" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
   <div class="input-group">
        <input type="Search" name="user_search" value="" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control" />
       <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-info">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
           </button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

now my **data2.php** code like

```
<?php 
                include("db/opendb.php"); 
                $username=$_POST['user_search'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name=='" .$username"'";
    $result = $conn ->query($query) or die("Query error");s
    ?>
    <table width="983" border="1" cellpadding="5" class="insertTable">
      <tr>

        <td width="50"><strong>user id</strong></td>
        <td width="109"><strong>user name</strong></td>
        <td width="40"><strong>user adress</strong></td>
        <td width="38"><strong>user phone no</strong></td>
        <td width="99"><strong>dept id</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
      ?>

      <tr>

        <td><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['user_adress']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['user_phone_no']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['dept_id']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
```

please can any body help me i am working hard on it but nothing happning results not showing
i am using search form to search values from data base but i am failed to get results my table name is"user" in data base please help
i will be very great full to you

Comment: `WHERE user_name==` one `=` too many here and missing dot for `'" .$username"'`. checking for errors would have avoided this debugging/typo question. and that `s` here `or die("Query error");s` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: thanks its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as a community wiki; I don't want rep from this.

`WHERE user_name==` there is one `=` too many here and missing dot for `'" .$username"'`. checking for errors would have helped you here.

Also, that `s` here `die("Query error");s` that shouldn't be there.

Your code is also prone to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

You should also check for empty fields against your POST array:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php